# Pandas dataframe set cell value from sum of rows with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to set for each row, the value of ART_IN_TICKET to be the number of rows that have the same TICKET_ID as this row.

for example, for the first 5 rows of this dataframe, TICKET_ID is 35592159 and ART_IN_TICKET should be 5 since there are 5 rows with that same TICKET_ID.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There can be other solutions as well. A relatively simple solution would be to get the count of rows for each `TICKET_ID` and then merge the new df with this one to get the final result in `ART_IN_TICKET`. Assuming the above dataframe is in `df`.

```
count_df = df[['TICKET_ID', 'ART_IN_TICKET']].groupby("TICKET_ID").count().reset_index()
df = df[list(set(df.columns.tolist())-set(["ART_IN_TICKET"]))] # Removing ART_IN_TICKET column before merging
final_df = df.merge(count_df, on="TICKET_ID")
```